# How to skip "manage your calendar" screen at a time of generate token?

Tags: api, google-calendar-api

Here I integrate Google Calendar API for add event in Google Calendar from my site.

But once I click to generate token link its redirect me on manage your calendar screen. I kindly skip this screen while generating token.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is required so you can't just skip it. This is the part of the authorization process for you to be able to perform tasks using the Calendar API. This is mentioned in the [Authorizing requests with OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth)

> ..
> 3. When your application needs access to user data, it asks Google for a particular scope of access.
>
> 4. Google displays a consent screen to the user, asking them to authorize your application to request some of their data.
> 5. If the user approves, then Google gives your application a short-lived access token.
> 6. Your application requests user data, attaching the access token to the request.
> 7. If Google determines that your request and the token are valid, it returns the requested data.

However, there's a programmatic way to access users data without any manual authorization on the users part. This is through [service accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatinganaccount).

Comment: Thanx for your replaying....

But in my case, I have simple form in that flied like (Booking appointment date, Name of booking, Desc).
I just need when user fill all the field and click to book appointment button. Appoint book in my(Admin) google calendar.

But currently when user click on booking appointment button, User redirect to given above screen. In that screen shown allow admin to access your(client) calendar.

In my case I don't want to access client calendar.

How can I add event/Appointment in my(admin) calendar without given above authentication.?

Thanks